# Force calls to libgcc

Tags: c, gcc, glibc, built-in, libgcc

As far as I understand, libgcc implements some libc functions which are called into when a program uses a built-in and gcc decides not to implement it by some inline assembly. Is it however possible to have gcc implement all built-ins as calls to libgcc always?

Answer (score 2):

Use: `-fno-builtin`, or:

`-fno-builtin-function`, for specific functions. e.g., `-fno-builtin-memcpy`